# How to distinguish between overloaded methods without if statements

Tags: java, overloading

In my program I receive a message from a call, that has a variable of the type Optional and depending on whether something is inside of this variable or not I shall make a call of a method with a parameter or a call to the same method without a parameter, standard overloading.

The problem I am having is that the produced code becomes ugly, especially the more optionals I receive the more distinguishing the method call becomes. Currently the next method call is determined via an if-else.

Here is a simplified code for this question, first the Message Class:

```
public class FooMessage {

  public Optional<String> receivedMessage;

  public FooMessage(String message) {
      this.receivedMessage = Optional.ofNullable(message);
  }
}
```

and then the Main class:

```
public class Main {

  public static FooMessage receiveMessageWithNull(){
      return new FooMessage(null);
  }

  public static FooMessage receiveMessage(String s){
      return new FooMessage(s);
  }

  public static void fooMethod() {
      System.out.println("Message == null");
  }

  public static void fooMethod(String message) {
      System.out.println("Message != null");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Calls that return a Message either with content or without
      FooMessage message = receiveMessage("foo");
      FooMessage messageWithNull = receiveMessageWithNull();
      //Resolving which version of the overloaded method to call
      if (message.receivedMessage.isPresent()) {
          fooMethod(message.receivedMessage.get());
      } else {
          fooMethod();
      }

      if (messageWithNull.receivedMessage.isPresent()) {
          fooMethod(messageWithNull.receivedMessage.get());
      } else {
          fooMethod();
      }
  }
}
```

My question is if there is a possibility to clean the code up in a way that the method call itself is written to resolve the checks currently done in the if statements. I was thinking about something like:

```
fooMethod(message.receivedMessage.isPresent() ? message.receivedMessage.get() : ... );
```

Instead of `...` there would be something that told the method to ignore the parameter.

Note: I cannot change `fooMethod`. I have to resolve which version of `fooMethod` has to be called in the calling method.

Comment: If options increase you can use switch statement. Otherwise this is the way to go.

Comment: Your methods (we don't say "functions" in Java) are *overloaded*, not *polymorphic*. Please be clear in your wording.

Comment: take look at [builder pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2)

Comment: can't you just have one `fooFunction` that allows a `null` String as parameter?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thanks for your hint, I updated the question

Comment: @payloc unfortunately I cannot change the fooFunctions or add a new overloaded version of them myself, since they are part of a class I have no access to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to execute the method **only if** the `Optional` value is present, and you do not care for an absent value, you may go with

```
message.receivedMessage.ifPresent(Main::fooMethod);
```

I would avoid passing the `Optional` to a method that then distinguishes whether the value is present, but you can implement a support function that would **hide the implementation details**

```
private static void distinguish(String s) {
    if (s == null) fooMethod();
    else fooMethod(s);
}
```

and cal it via

```
distinguish(message.receivedMessage.orElse(null));
```

This is an acceptable way of using `Òptional::orElse`.

From the docs:

```
 /**
 * Return the value if present, otherwise return {@code other}.
 *
 * @param other the value to be returned if there is no value present, may
 * be null
 * @return the value, if present, otherwise {@code other}
 */
public T orElse(T other) {
    return value != null ? value : other;
}
```

---

I would personally just stick with `if (optional.isPresent())` as this is what optionals are intended for, so I wouldn't worry too much.